Pass AVAudioPCMBuffer.floatChannelData from Swift to Obj-C (C++)
I have the following function to process audio data in Obj-C (and then deeper in C++):
- (void) audioProcess: (int) numChannels
           numSamples: (int) numSamples
               stride: (int) stride
                 data: (float * const *) data;

This signature is classic for processing audio buffer data stored in contiguous memory. It could be interleaved or not, depending on the buffer.
Then in Swift, I want to process an audio buffer like so:
let buffer = ... // get AVAudioPCMBuffer from somewhere

if let floatChannelData = buffer.floatChannelData {

    audioProcess(Int32(buffer.format.channelCount),
                 numSamples: Int32(buffer.frameLength),
                 stride: Int32(buffer.stride),
                 data: floatChannelData)
}

I get the following compilation error:

Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?>'

Notice the difference in optionality of the UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.
How can I pass the floatChannelData from Swift to Obj-C (C++)?
Edit: typos

The issue here is that Objective-C allows nullable pointers, and Swift has strict typing around optional and non-optional pointers.
Since floatChannelData is of type UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer>, you can map it to the correct type using this conversion:
if let floatChannelData = buffer.floatChannelData {
    // Convert the pointer to the expected form
    let data = UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?>(floatChannelData)
    
    audioProcess(Int32(buffer.format.channelCount),
                 numSamples: Int32(buffer.frameLength),
                 stride: Int32(buffer.stride),
                 data: data)
}

different UnsafePointer for Swift and Objective-C/C++
